# OpenSSL vs. Phpseclib

Tags: openssl, phpseclib

OpenSSL vs. Phpseclib

What is your opinion, I'm looking to do rsa and hashing. I'd like it to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with phpseclib myself on the basis that it's a lot easier to use and deploy than OpenSSL is.  OpenSSL's going to be faster, if you can get it working, but that's a big if.

One problem with OpenSSL is that it only accepts public keys if they're in the form of X.509 certificates.  It's also not as widely deployed on servers as one might like (meaning that code that uses it is going to be less portable) and even on those servers that it is deployed on you're liable to have issues with misconfigured openssl.cnf files.